# Criando uma função para highslide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou usando o highslide, para abrir as páginas internas.

O chato é que ele tem o comando `onclick` muito grande:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="comercialContatoAdicionar.php?i=2a" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 900, height: 700, preserveContent: false } )">Adicionar novo contato</a>
```

É possivel transformar esse comando do `onclick` em uma função ou algo que deixar o link menor.

Obrigado.

Comment: São vários links na página ou um só?

Comment: São vários, por isso to tentando mudar, tem horas que preciso mexer o scroll horizontal para ver o código.

Comment: A resposta do Hugocss deve resolver então.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível sim vc pode fazer um `forEach()` e executar a função para cada btn clicado individualmente...

```js
let meulink = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-success');

function frame(el){
  console.log(el.target);
  // return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 900, height: 700, preserveContent: false } );
}

meulink.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', frame)
});
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#" >contato 111</a>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#" >contato 222</a>
```

Comment: Em vez de `el.target` vc pode usar simplesmente `this`.

Comment: @Sam valeu o toque, this ainda eh meio confuso pra mim ainda rss